# Failed to load TEX extension from http source

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm deploying a Google web app to write commutative diagrams with LaTeX/Xy-pic.
In the heading of html page I put the following configuration:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
"HTML-CSS": {
  styles: {".MathJax_Preview": {visibility: "hidden"}}
},
tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]},
TeX: {extensions: 
["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","http://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax_ext/xypic.js"]}
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js"> 
</script>
```

The problem is that the file *http://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax_ext/xypic.js* is not loaded because it is from an http source. This is the message I read in console:

```
MathJax.js:19 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://script.google.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax_ext/xypic.js?V=2.7.5'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I try to use *https://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax_ext/xypic.js* instead, but this doesn't work at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome. This is an edge case, as for one side, questions about developing web apps are off-topic but question about using web applications, like Google Apps Script are on topic.

Answer (score 2):

One way to prevent the error message described on the question is to copy the code from the referred JavaScript library to the Google Apps Script project.

The above could be done in several ways that will depend on how you prefer to manage your code, but according to the best practices on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascriptHTML, CSS and JavaScript should be kept on separate files. This implies to use a template like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Please enjoy this helpful script.</p>
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where JavaScript is the file name of the file holding the JavaScript code. The name actually could be almost anything that makes sense to you and even you would have your JavaScript code on several files, like having one for you own code and another for the referred JavaScript library.